# Swift - adding buttonTapped function in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` in which I have custom `cells` ("WishCell"). Inside of that `cell` is a `UIButton` but somehow the linked `func checkButtonTapped` is not working. It doesn't even `print`... I have no idea why this code is not working:

```
    class WhishCell: UITableViewCell {
    
    let label: UILabel = {
       let v = UILabel()
        v.font = UIFont(name: "AvenirNext", size: 23)
        v.textColor = .white
        v.font = v.font.withSize(23)
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return v
    }()
    
        let checkButton: UIButton =  {
        let v = UIButton()
        v.backgroundColor = .darkGray
//        v.layer.borderColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
//        v.layer.borderWidth = 2.0
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        v.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "boxUnchecked"), for: .normal)
        v.addTarget(self, action: #selector(checkButtonTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
        return v
    }()
    
    
    
    public static let reuseID = "WhishCell"

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")}

    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        
        self.backgroundColor = .clear
        
        // add checkButton
        self.contentView.addSubview(checkButton)
        self.checkButton.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leadingAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
        self.checkButton.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        self.checkButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40).isActive = true
        self.checkButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40).isActive = true
        
        // add label
        self.contentView.addSubview(label)
        self.label.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leadingAnchor, constant: 60).isActive = true
        self.label.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        
        
        
    }
    
    @objc func checkButtonTapped(){
        print("hi")
        self.checkButton.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "boxChecked"), for: .normal)
        self.checkButton.alpha = 0
        self.checkButton.transform =  CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.3, y: 1.3)
        
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {
            self.checkButton.alpha = 1
            self.checkButton.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
        }
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: can you check the view hierarchy? I think that the label is over the button

Comment: @AndresGomez nope just checked it. It even does the "click"-animation

Comment: First, don't call your variables with single letters like "v", be more informative.
Second, it is better to use the delegation pattern. In the table view controller declared the class that will be the delegate for this cell and call the delegate method in the button event. Are you using storyboards? it will make life easier and save you coding time, like adding buttons manually.

Comment: sorry for the variable name. Is anything not clear? And in my case doing this programmatically is actually easier :) Do you have any idea why it is not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this

```
class WhishCell: UITableViewCell {

    let label: UILabel = {
        let v = UILabel()
        v.font = UIFont(name: "AvenirNext", size: 23)
        v.textColor = .black
        v.font = v.font.withSize(23)
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return v
    }()

    let checkButton: UIButton =  {
        let v = UIButton()
        v.backgroundColor = .blue
        //        v.layer.borderColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
        //        v.layer.borderWidth = 2.0
        v.clipsToBounds = true
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        v.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "boxUnchecked"), for: .normal)
        return v
    }()

    public static let reuseID = "WhishCell"
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")}

    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

        self.backgroundColor = .clear

        // add checkButton
        self.contentView.addSubview(checkButton)
        self.checkButton.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leadingAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
        self.checkButton.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        self.checkButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40).isActive = true
        self.checkButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40).isActive = true
        self.checkButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(checkButtonTapped), for: .touchUpInside)

        // add label
        self.contentView.addSubview(label)
        self.label.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leadingAnchor, constant: 60).isActive = true
        self.label.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    }

    @objc func checkButtonTapped() {
        print("hi")
        self.checkButton.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "boxChecked"), for: .normal)
        self.checkButton.alpha = 0
        self.checkButton.transform =  CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.3, y: 1.3)

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {
            self.checkButton.alpha = 1
            self.checkButton.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: it works! Why does it only work if you `addTarget` afterwards?

Comment: It works because your target is the cell and not the button itself.